# DateDiff Formula in a UserForm

Tags: vba, date, userform, datediff

I have two textboxes that contain a start date and a end date.

I want to get a number that represents the days that are between those two.

```vb
Private Sub TextBox20_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    'check date format
    With TextBox20
        If IsDate(TextBox20.Text) Then 'Format as desired.
            TextBox20.Text = Format(CDate(TextBox20.Text), "Dddd, d Mmm yyyy", vbMonday)
        Else
            TextBox20.Text = "" 'Clear the TextBox
            MsgBox "Por favor, ingresar una fecha valida."
            Cancel = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox21_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    'check date format
    With TextBox21
        If IsDate(TextBox21.Text) Then 'Format as desired.
            TextBox21.Text = Format(CDate(TextBox21.Text), "Dddd, d Mmm yyyy", vbMonday)
        Else
            TextBox21.Text = "" 'Clear the TextBox
            MsgBox "Por favor, ingresar una fecha valida."
            Cancel = True
            Exit Sub
        End If    
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox22_AfterUpdate()
TextBox22.Value = DateDiff("d", CDate(TextBox20.Value), CDate(TextBox21.Value), vbMonday)    
End Sub
```

I thought it was because I had the TextBoxes as `.Text` and not `.Value`, but yet nothing changes.

Comment: Posted an approach close to your code which should give you some ideas in studying UserForm behaviour. Feel free to accept if helpful. - FYI you might profit from reading [UserForm1.Show?](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) as an advanced introduction into structured and maintainable MVP coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Correct calculation of `DateDiff` based on textbox strings**

Though I generally *do* advise against *overwriting* original control entries (of dates) to a reformatted (date) string in your textboxes, I demonstrate a possible way very close to your approach. This includes some provisions for a readable date string in order to allow a `DateDiff()` calculation.

**Declaration head of UserForm code module**

In order to hold the correct starting and end dates (as `Date` type and *not* as string), I define a `Type` structure, that can be reused easily in the subsequent procedures.

```
Option Explicit

Private Type TThis
    StartDate As Date
    EndDate   As Date
End Type
Dim this      As TThis
```

**Example procedures**

- `Sub CheckDays()` calculates the `DateDiff` based on the entries in the type structure as declared above. It differs from your code as the calculation function is called each time after exiting the textbox inputs.
- `Function getDateString()` tries to make the TextBox strings convertible to the Date type by adapting formatting results that would lead to a wrong date conversion. A final `IsDate()` check is made in the textboxes' event procedures before calling `CheckDays` calculation.

```
Private Sub CheckDays()
' Purpose: calculate DateDiff and enter result into TextBox22
' Note   : called by TextBox20_Exit|TextBox21_Exit events
If this.StartDate > 0 And this.EndDate >= this.StartDate Then
    TextBox22.Text = DateDiff("d", this.StartDate, this.EndDate, vbMonday)
End If
End Sub

Private Function getDateString(ByVal txt As String) As String
' Purpose: make (TextBox) string convertible to Date type, if possible
   'a) remove leading day names (e.g. "Wednesday, 1 Jan 2020" ~> "1 Jan 2020")
    If InStr(txt, ",") > 0 Then txt = Split(txt, ",")(1)
   'b) add current year if missing (e.g. "1.1." ~> "1.1.2020")
    If Not IsDate(txt) Then
        If IsDate(txt & " " & Year(Now)) Then txt = txt & " " & Year(Now)
    End If
    getDateString = txt                     ' return function result
End Function
```

**UserForm event procedures**

These procedures are left nearly unchanged, but include

- a `DateString` assignment via `getDateString() to provide for convertible date strings as well as
- the procedure call of `CheckDays` to calculate the `DateDiff` and enter the result into `TextBox22`.

*Additional note:* Instead of `_Exit` events it would have been possible to use the `_AfterUpDate` events, too.

```
Private Sub TextBox20_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
With TextBox20
    Dim DateString As String
    DateString = getDateString(.Text)       'Make TextBox string convertible to Date type.

    'check date format
    If IsDate(DateString) Then              'Format as desired.
        this.StartDate = CDate(DateString)  'Remember date (Date type).
        .Text = Format(this.StartDate, "Dddd, d Mmm yyyy", vbMonday)
        '========
        CheckDays                           '<< Call procedure to calculate DateDiff.
        '--------
    Else
        .Text = ""                          'Clear the TextBox string
        this.EndDate = 0
        MsgBox "Por favor, ingresar una fecha valida."
        Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub TextBox21_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
With TextBox21
    Dim DateString As String
    DateString = getDateString(.Text)       'Make TextBox string convertible to Date type.

    'check date format
    If IsDate(DateString) Then              'Format as desired.
        this.EndDate = CDate(DateString)    'Remember date (Date type).
        .Text = Format(this.EndDate, "Dddd, d Mmm yyyy", vbMonday)
        '========
        CheckDays                           '<< call procedure to calculate DateDiff
        '--------
    Else
        .Text = ""                          'Clear the TextBox string
        this.EndDate = 0
        MsgBox "Por favor, ingresar una fecha valida."
        Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With
End Sub
```